# python pandas dataframe trend indicator running in for loop how to avoid loop and optimize this code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

This is one of the trend indicator called super trend which obviously giving very accurate results and the results are matching with major websites wherein it is supported.

this method actually uses calculated ATR value as input, Since the entire calculation is in for loop it takes hell lot of time.

stockdata is a dataframe which has Date,Open,High,Low,Close values and this is passed as input.

input structure (from atr the calculated output - supert ,supert1,supert3 ) are the output made by calling ST three times ,if this is a function which will only return ST value that can be easily appended in existing dataframe .

```
            open    high     low    close   atr lband2  finaluband  finaluband1 finaluband2 finallband  finallband1 finallband2 supert  supert1 supert2
date                                                            
01-07-02    5.2397  5.5409  5.2397  5.4127  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
02-07-02    5.5234  5.537   5.4214  5.4438  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
03-07-02    5.506   5.5458  5.3281  5.4661  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
04-07-02    5.5011  5.572   5.4175  5.5283  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
05-07-02    5.5633  5.6566  5.4749  5.5905  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
08-07-02    5.5011  5.7187  5.5011  5.6255  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
09-07-02    5.5905  5.7586  5.5681  5.6167  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10-07-02    5.4885  5.4885  5.1465  5.2222  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11-07-02    4.9784  5.2135  4.9784  5.1863  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12-07-02    5.5011  5.5011  5.2446  5.3194  NaN 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15-07-02    5.3243  5.4797  5.1912  5.333   0.24036 4.61437 5.57581 5.81617 6.05653 5.09509 4.85473 4.61437 5.57581 5.81617 6.05653
16-07-02    5.1999  5.4389  5.1999  5.3155  0.240224    4.598728    5.559624    5.799848    6.040072    5.09509 4.85473 4.61437 5.559624    5.799848    6.040072
17-07-02    4.7024  5.1377  4.6189  5.0445  0.285862    4.020715    5.164162    5.450023    5.735885    5.09509 4.85473 4.61437 5.164162    5.450023    5.735885
18-07-02    4.8803  5.1465  4.8356  5.0804  0.288365    4.125954    5.164162    5.450023    5.735885    4.702685    4.85473 4.61437 5.164162    5.450023    5.735885
19-07-02    5.027   5.2038  5.0221  5.1513  0.277699    4.279853    5.164162    5.450023    5.735885    4.835251    4.85473 4.61437 5.164162    5.450023    5.735885
22-07-02    5.0804  5.1465  4.9687  4.9735  0.268189    4.253033    5.164162    5.450023    5.735885    4.835251    4.85473 4.61437 5.164162    5.450023    5.735885
23-07-02    4.8181  5.0843  4.8181  5.0619  0.26799 4.14723 5.164162    5.450023    5.735885    4.835251    4.85473 4.61437 5.164162    5.450023    5.735885
24-07-02    5.058   5.129   4.9376  5.0619  0.260331    4.252307    5.164162    5.450023    5.735885    4.835251    4.85473 4.61437 5.164162    5.450023    5.735885
25-07-02    5.058   5.058   4.7918  4.8492  0.261308    4.140976    5.164162    5.447516    5.708824    4.835251    4.85473 4.61437 5.164162    5.447516    5.708824
26-07-02    5.1465  5.1465  4.7297  4.8715  0.276857    4.107528    5.164162    5.447516    5.708824    4.835251    4.384386    4.61437 5.164162    5.447516    5.708824
29-07-02    4.2235  4.2507  3.9038  4.2507  0.345941    3.039426    4.423191    4.769133    5.115074    4.835251    4.384386    4.61437 4.423191    4.769133    5.115074
30-07-02    4.17    4.3255  4.0369  4.2769  0.340207    3.160578    4.423191    4.769133    5.115074    3.840993    3.500785    3.160578    4.423191    4.769133    5.115074
31-07-02    4.1797  4.3031  4.1486  4.2108  0.321637    3.26094 4.423191    4.769133    5.115074    3.904213    3.582577    3.26094 4.423191    4.769133    5.115074
01-08-02    4.2507  4.5169  4.2507  4.4586  0.320083    3.423551    4.423191    4.769133    5.115074    4.063717    3.743634    3.423551    4.063717    4.769133    5.115074
02-08-02    4.068   4.6101  4.068   4.4984  0.342285    3.312196    4.681335    4.769133    5.115074    4.063717    3.743634    3.423551    4.063717    4.769133    5.115074
05-08-02    4.5965  4.7918  4.5256  4.7918  0.337396    3.646511    4.681335    4.769133    5.115074    4.321304    3.983908    3.646511    4.321304    3.983908    5.115074
06-08-02    4.6276  4.6811  4.6276  4.65    0.320077    3.69412 4.974427    5.294503    5.115074    4.334273    4.014197    3.69412 4.334273    4.014197    5.115074
07-08-02    4.8006  4.854   4.6587  4.752   0.308469    3.830943    4.974427    5.294503    5.115074    4.447881    4.139412    3.830943    4.447881    4.139412    5.115074
08-08-02    4.7918  4.7918  4.614   4.65    0.295402    3.816694    4.974427    5.293704    5.115074    4.447881    4.139412    3.830943    4.447881    4.139412    5.115074
09-08-02    4.6587  4.7024  4.5742  4.7024  0.278682    3.802255    4.916982    5.195664    5.115074    4.447881    4.139412    3.830943    4.447881    4.139412    5.115074
```

How this code can be rewritten so that without having for loop the same results can be achieved without compromizing the accuracy.I expect a single function call which will give "supert" value in pandas dataframe format added to stockdata.

```
def ST(high, low, close, atr, prevfinaluband, prevfinallband, prevsupertrend,
       prevclose, multiplier):
    upperbasicband = ((high+low)/2 + (multiplier * atr))
    lowerbasicband = ((high+low)/2 - (multiplier * atr))
    if upperbasicband < prevfinaluband or prevclose > prevfinaluband:
        upperband = upperbasicband
    else:
        upperband = prevfinaluband
    if lowerbasicband > prevfinallband or prevclose < prevfinallband:
        lowerband = lowerbasicband
    else:
        lowerband = prevfinallband

    if prevsupertrend == prevfinaluband:
        if close <= upperband:
            supertrend = upperband
        else:
            supertrend = lowerband
    else:
        if prevsupertrend == prevfinallband:
            if close >= lowerband:
                supertrend = lowerband
            else:
                supertrend = upperband
        else:
            supertrend = 0.0

    return upperbasicband, lowerbasicband, upperband, lowerband, supertrend



for i in range(1, len(stockdata)):
    if np.isnan(stockdata['atr'][i]):
        continue
    uband, lband, finaluband, finallband, supert =\
        customindicator.ST(stockdata['high'][i], stockdata['low'][i],
           stockdata['close'][i], stockdata['atr'][i],
           stockdata['finaluband'][i-1], stockdata['finallband'][i-1],
            stockdata['supert'][i-1], stockdata['close'][i-1],
            multiplier =7)
```

I am trying this optimization so that it will run faster. I am ok to pass as much as a parameter to a function.If you have a solution please post.

Comment: Please provide `stockdata` sample and structure. And expected outputs on that sample.

Comment: `numpy.where()` might help you here.

Comment: data sample provided.

Comment: Please provide working sample of ST call. I'm pretty sure that i misunderstood how it should work.

Comment: `prevsupertrend == prevfinaluband`  it's a bad idea to compare floating point values directly. Usually they are slightly different.`abs(prevsupertrend - prevfinaluband)<e` where `e` is accuracy you need.

Answer (score 0):

### **Update 3**

I was unable to reproduce results in given sample with given ST implementation. Sorry.

But I updated code to return same shape as in sample and skip NaN.

---

Vectorization will give you huge improvement.  Like **31.4 ms** vectorized version vs **14.9 seconds** original on sample of 10**5 values.

```
#generate sample
n = 10**5
stockdata = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(n,7)),

            columns = ['atr','high', 'low','close','finaluband','finallband','supert'])
print (stockdata.shape)
stockdata.head()
```

SuperST will return all `DataFrame` on `stockdata`
`for i in range(3)` it is exactly loop of different multiplied, your can rewrite it as `for i in [7,8,9]: SuperST(stockdata,estim,i)`

You ST realisation is depends on results of previous call. It uses `'finaluband','finallband','supert'` and returns them by itself. Initially they are zeros, but after first call they will have some value. So `estim` give you control on that situation, you can call `SuperST` with results of previous call or with initial zeros. Just rename initial DataFrame with zeros and pass it to  `SuperST`.

```
df_res = stockdata
estim = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((df_res.shape[0],5)), index = df_res.index,
                         columns=['uband', 'lband', 'finaluband', 'finallband', 'supert'])

for i in range(3):
    estim = SuperST(stockdata,estim)
    df_res = df_res.join(estim,rsuffix="{}".format(i))
    print(df_res[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'atr', 'lband2', 'finaluband',
       'finaluband1', 'finaluband2', 'finallband', 'finallband1',
       'finallband2', 'supert', 'supert1', 'supert2']])
```

SuperST is the same ST

```
def SuperST(stockdata,estim,multiplier = 7):
    #first we need next row value
    df_prev = estim[['finaluband','finallband','supert']].join(stockdata[['close']]).shift(1)
    # name colums as it was in paramas
    df_prev.columns = ['prevfinaluband', 'prevfinallband', 'prevsupertrend', 'prevclose']
    # working matrix parmas with shifed values w/o NaN in ATR
    df = stockdata.dropna().join(df_prev).fillna(0)

    #calulate vectors 
    upperbasicband = ((df.high+df.low)/2 + (multiplier * df.atr))
    lowerbasicband = ((df.high+df.low)/2 - (multiplier * df.atr))
    # np.where is a vector version of if
    upperband = np.where((upperbasicband < df.prevfinaluband) | (df.prevclose > df.prevfinaluband),
                        upperbasicband,df.prevfinaluband)
    lowerband = np.where ((lowerbasicband > df.prevfinallband) | (df.prevclose < df.prevfinallband),
                         lowerbasicband,df.prevfinallband)

    supertrend = np.where (df.prevsupertrend == df.prevfinaluband,
                             np.where(df.close <= upperband,
                                      upperband,lowerband),
                          np.where(df.prevsupertrend == df.prevfinallband,
                                      np.where(df.close >= lowerband,
                                              lowerband,upperband),
                                    np.zeros_like(lowerband)))


    return upperbasicband.to_frame('uband').assign( 
                    lband = lowerbasicband).assign(
                    finaluband = upperband).assign(
                    finallband = lowerband).assign(
                    supert = supertrend)
```

Comment: The atr has NaN value in SeperSt how this is handled?

Comment: your update1 was good where everything done inside the SuperST and i felt i can just do atr calculation as well inside the SperST. Now with this "for i in range(3):"  i feel the scalability is gone . Assume i need to call ths SuperST for 10 times with differrent multiplied then the for loop given above also to be repeated which is time lagging .why is this estim added now . Can you also post yesterdays solution seperately ,let me try both and tell you the optimized solution.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have it, but nothing is changed in terms of scalability. See comments in update 3:)

By the way, current implementation look very "exel" way of thinking. It looks ugly, but i can't suggest you any improvements because I don't see full scope of the task.

Comment: i see estim is making trouble here ,we have data in stockdata and that has to be passed to SuperST(stockdata,Multiplier=7) that is it .The estim and for loop not required . The return should be only Supertrend value .So that anywhere in the code this function can be called any any times . If we add for roop again that will add lag.

Comment: The above solution let me check and feedback today. Please do not change it.

Comment: I think problem is deeper :(  . I'm pretty sure that i misunderstood how it should work. SuperST do not refer results of previous timestamp calculations. It uses vector `finaluband` as it is, and do not update it incrementally inside calculation. That type of update is unusual for relational calculation which is pandas for. So you need different algorithm with the same results, not just vectorization of current function.
Please provide **working code of ST call**: input table, code, output table.

Comment: Or if it is problematic to make it work, link to original algorithm description or spreadsheet. We need to be on the same page on what you program should do, now i'm guessing what do you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165638/discussion-between-marx-babu-and-ilia-timofeev).